# About Multilingual Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Can you please suggest to me the best way to make a Multilingual Website that shows text in the selected language but at time of saving to the database have it saved in English?

There is a hurdle: my website uses some Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Internationalization-Globalization-in-Silverlight-Part-1-Terminology.aspx

Comment: can we make multilingual silver light application without resource files?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably, will it be as easy as resource files? probably not

Answer (score -1):

if it is still relevant I was using Gtranslate plugin on my website for years. Very comfortable. The big advantage: You will have each language version in a dedicated URL - meaning you will get more exposure on the search enginese. But the disadvantages: I suppose it add some load time to your webpages, and of course the monthly payment for subscription.